# eclips source not found debug remotely

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I want to debug remote java app but source not found with button to click source? Do I attach source to eac lib? I am use `maven` adn spring mvc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree, another option is to force the sources once the debug is started:

View Debug> (Right in the main)> Edit Source Lookup Path> Add> Select the source

Finally assign it a high priority with the "Up"

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Select the project related to debug:

Debug configurations > (Select your remote Java application) > Connection > Project > Button "Browse" > Select the project that has the source code > Apply > Debug

Regards,

Comment: i already did this one thing. attempts at debugging at step through procedure (f6) makes IDE pause debugging and says "source not found"

Comment: This happens because it has associated the sources, if you associate the project with the project's main sources or sources associated debug you should appear